# Is Vim-gnome FuzzyFinder plugin broken since Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: gvim, vim-plugin

After Ubuntu 13.04 installation I simply unzip an archive with all my **gvim** setup, ie.

```
.vim/
.vim-fuf
.viminfo
.vimrc
```

After doing a clean install of Ubuntu 13.04, I unzipped my Vim config as usual. When I pressed the shortcut for FuzzyFinder that shows a dropdown of file matches, it displayed a red error at bottom:

```
Error detected while processing function fuf#onComplete..15..14..<SNR>23_setRanks..<SNR>23_scoreSequentialMatching:
line   2:
E806: using Float as a String
```

Has there been a recent rebuild of vim-gnome that would explain this errror? I'm on 7.3.547.

The .vim folder is extremely portable, I've used it accross Windows, LinuxMint, Mac OS, and never came across this error, which is why I am wondering if this could be an error in the Vim build itself.

**Update** I also deleted `.vim-fuf` and `.viminfo` just in case, and the error stills appears.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by downloading the latest version of [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) (v4.2.2) as well as the dependency [L9 Vim script library](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3252) (v1.1).

I honestly have no idea why it would stop working after updating to Ubuntu 13.04 (from 12.10). As said in question, I unzip the same .vim/ archive I use between various OS and never had this issue. It was working in 12.10 this morning. I checked the archive for errors, there were none.

So I guess *something* must have changed in the Vim build or the environment in 13.04.